# Jenkins Console Output Format

Tags: git, jenkins, kubernetes-helm

When I prepare a job which includes "helm diff" or "git diff", the output format is too difficult to read(it is just plain-text) and there must be a plugin or a way to see these kinds of outputs in a better format even as a colourfull format.
Could you help me to find a solution for that?

Comment: Check on the [AnsiColor Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/AnsiColor+Plugin), i have not personally used it yet but its quite polular.

Comment: Although I have added inside of Jenkinsfile---> options {ansiColor('xterm')},  I still get an error like that: ...java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'options' found among steps ...

Comment: Thanks, @dominik-gebhart, this plugin has helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, "AnsiColor Plugin" helped me, but correct "ansiColor('xterm')" configuration has taken my so time

the config below has fixed my problem

> ```
>     ansiColor('xterm') {
>        sh "command"
>      }
> ```

the config below did not work on me

> ```
>       options {
>         ansiColor('xterm')
>        }
> ```